# Lambda Expression pointer

Tags: c++, function, lambda

Just started working with lambdas.  I wanted to create pointer to array. I think that I searched the whole internet and every sigle tutorial and I didn't find the answer.

```
auto c = []() -> int* { int* b = new int[10]; b[0] = 2; b[1] = 2; return b; };
std::cout << sizeof(c()) << std::endl;
delete c();
```

The sizeof(c) is always returning 4 even if arrar size is 1000. And my question is can you actually do it?

Comment: On your platform, the size of an `int*` is 4 bytes.

Comment: You're using the wrong `delete`.

Comment: You are leaking the 1st array, since you are calling the array twice, thus allocating 2 arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sizeof(c) is always returning 4 even if arrar size is 1000.

If on your platform, the size of a pointer is 4, then the result is expected and correct.

```
[]() -> int* { int* b = new int[10]; b[0] = 2; b[1] = 2; return b; }
```

This lambda returns a `int*`.

So, the `sizeof` is actually returning the size of the `int*` type, not the size of the `int[10]` type.

Comment: There is no array decay happening in this code